# how to integrate akka, camel and servicemix with jetty

Tags: apache-camel, akka, jetty, apache-servicemix

I have some actors written in *akka*, and I would like to make them interact through *ServiceMix*. Tough, I am a bit confused about how these technologies interact. 
This is what I have understood so far:

- *akka* let me write some actors:

  - producer sends messages
  - consumer receives messages
  - untypedActor both send and receive
- *akka* *microkernel* bundles up all the actors in just one jar file
- *camel* is the bridge between akka and ServiceMix, since it exposes actors over http (with jetty for example)
- *ServiceMix* let actors communicate

Each actor will be available on a fixed endpoint, defined as route in *ServiceMix*

```
from("jetty:http://localhost:{{port}}/myapp/myactor").process(new MyActor());
```

Now my questions are:

1. who automatically deploys my actors in *jetty*?
2. how can I define the endpoints of the actors?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your questions:

1) no one, you deploy your bundle in service mix and camel opens a jetty endpoint for you to listen on that port for http requests.
2) According to the akka documentation there is a akka endpoint already available. You need to install some sort of "camel-akka" bundle to use it. There seems to be some documentation for this available from the [akka](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/camel.html) page

Comment: 1) so, I should not manually deploy my actors in jetty: it's already done by ServiceMix    2) in akka documentation there is _jetty:http://localhost:8877/example_ , so it seems I could use whatever endpoint... and camel will open that port? And ServiceMix automatically know that should deploy those actors on those ports?  it's a kind of magic :)

Comment: ServiceMix is just the runtime-container. The route you describe is managed by Camel, which runs in ServiceMix. Jetty will just be used by Camel, so Camel does take care of this.